# SSIS and Informatica

Tags: ssis, informatica-powercenter, sql-server-2012-datatools, sql-server-2014

SQL SERVER 2014 SSIS has been released,we have already got lot of facilities in SQL SERVER 2012 SSIS.Can anybody compare SSIS 2014/SSIS2012 with Informatica Power center ? What are the additional fetures are there in the Informatica new version than SSIS 2012/2014? Or are there functions in SSIS 2014/20122 ,which are not available in Informatica.

I still can not understand why clients are investing in very expensive tools like Informatica,If we have reliable and effective tool like ssis.
Experts Please have a discussion on this

Comment: Is there any body used informatica and ssis

Answer (score 3):

This would take some time to name all the differences. These products are quite similar at the first glance, but I'll try to name few features that would distinguish them. (I haven't been working with SSIS for many years now so please feel free to name any mistakes I make.) Here goes:

- PowerCenter (PC) can run on grid distributing work across nodes
- PC is able to connect to:

  - Messaging platforms (e.g. Tibco)
  - Salesforce
  - social media sources
  - Hadoop
  - SAP
- PC can run on Unix
- allows Real Time integration
- allow data lineage from underlying database up to reporting layer
- allows assigning memory per component
- allows to easily see number of rows passing each transformation

This is just to name a few. Feel free to add / comment.

Comment: Ok that sounds great.If the data requirement is only to integrate from muliple data bases like oracle and SQL Servers then SSIS is more than enough rt?